# MongoDB Aggregation: summation of 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, vector, sum, aggregation-framework

I want to do a summation of 2 array via the aggregation pipeline in MongoDB.

My Data:

```
{ "_id": "1", "Type": "A", "Data": [ [ 0, 1, 0 ] , [ 0, 1, 0 ],  [ 2, 0, 0 ] ] }
{ "_id": "2", "Type": "A", "Data": [ [ 2, 1, 0 ] , [ 0, 6, 0 ],  [ 3, 0, 0 ] ] }
{ "_id": "3", "Type": "B", "Data": [ [ 0, 1, 0 ] , [ 0, 2, 0 ],  [ 0, 0, 0 ] ] }
```

I want to build the sum on each element of the array

```
0 1 0   2 1 0   2 2 0
0 1 0 + 0 6 0 = 0 7 0
2 0 0   0 0 0   2 0 0
```

So my result should look like this:

```
{ "_id": {"Type" : "A"}, "Data": [ [ 2, 2, 0 ] , [ 0, 7, 0 ],  [ 2, 0, 0 ] ] }
{ "_id": {"Type" : "B"}, "Data": [ [ 0, 1, 0 ] , [ 0, 2, 0 ],  [ 0, 0, 0 ] ] }
```

I've started with grouping of the elements and building the $sum :

```
[{"$group": 
    { "_id": { "Type" : "$Type" },
      "Data": {"$sum" : "$Data"}
    }
}]
```

This works with single value data like a int, but not with an array. So, how can I do this? (I really hope there is a solution without a for loop)

Comment: Do you mean: `[ [ 0, 1, 0 ] , [ 0, 1, 0 ],  [ 2, 0, 0 ] ]`?

Comment: Oh my mistake, I'll correct this

Answer (score 0):

You can unwind the array with the index included, then sum over the indexes.

I come up with this solution but I think the performance is horrible if you have lots of document:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$match: {}},
    {$unwind: {path: '$Data', includeArrayIndex: 'l1'}},
    {$unwind: {path: '$Data', includeArrayIndex: 'l2'}},

    {$group: {_id: {type: '$Type', l1: '$l1', l2: '$l2'}, val: {$sum: '$Data'}}},

    {$sort: {'_id.type': 1, '_id.l1': 1, '_id.l2': 1}},
    {$group: {_id: {type: '$_id.type', l1: '$_id.l1'}, l2: {$push: '$val'}}},

    {$sort: {'_id.type': 1, '_id.l1': 1}},
    {$group: {_id: '$_id.type', final: {$push: '$l2'}}},

    {$sort: {_id: 1}}
])
```

The output is:

```
{ "_id" : "A", "Data" : [ [ 2.0, 2.0, 0.0 ], [ 0.0, 7.0, 0.0 ], [ 5.0, 0.0, 0.0 ] ] } 
{ "_id" : "B", "Data" : [ [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ], [ 0.0, 2.0, 0.0 ], [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ] ] }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's why I've mentioned without any for loops. The pipline above really looks into each array (mine is multpile layers deep, not only 2). I was hoping that there is a function like it is in Matlab.

Comment: I had tested this for a while, but I really don't like the solution. In Matlab it's so simple that I will stay with Matlab since I want to use it anyway. If anyone knows an other solution, feel free to answer! Thank you